how to use CookieStore in Angular in order to listen to cookie change events
I have an angular component where I would like to perform actions when a specific cookie is changed. I read that I can do it via CookieStore Api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CookieStore/change_event)
But when I try to use it in my angular component, the code does not compile:
    ngOnInit() {
   
        if ('cookieStore' in window) {
            // Listen for changes to cookies
            window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', event => {
                event.changed.forEach(change => {
                    console.log(`Cookie changed: ${change.name} = ${change.value}`);
                }); 
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Cookie Store API is not supported in this browser.');
        }
    }

Error is
TS2339: Property cookieStore does not exist on type Window & typeof globalThis

I am using angular version: 15.2.10. Is there any way I can use the CookieStore Api in my angular code? Either service or component?

It's not enough to define Window.cookieStore, you also need to define the CookieStore type and the event listener overload
type CookieChangeType = {
  name: string,
  value: string,
  expires: Date,
  domain: string,
}

interface CookieChangeEvent extends Event {
  changed: CookieChangeType[]
}

type CookieStore = {
  addEventListener: Window["addEventListener"]
}

declare global { 
  interface Window { 
    cookieStore: CookieStore; 
    addEventListener(type: String, listener: (this: Window, ev: CookieChangeEvent) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
  } 
}

Now your ngOnInit will use the new types, and not throw any type errors
ngOnInit() {
  window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', (event: CookieChangeEvent) => {
    event.changed.forEach((change: CookieChangeType) => {
        console.log(`Cookie changed: ${change.name} = ${change.value}`);
    })
  })
}


where should I place this first piece of code? in which file?

I added it at the top of the my-component.component.ts file, before export class MyComponent {}

Everything works as expected, I miss only the ability to cancel the subscription, I have created a separate question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79214374/how-to-cancel-subscription-to-window-cookiestore-addeventlistenerchange-in

You can resolve this by extending the Window interface to include cookieStore. Create a declaration file (e.g., window.d.ts) and add
declare global { 
  interface Window { 
    cookieStore: CookieStore; 
  } 
}

This will let TypeScript recognize the API and compile correctly.
Stackblitz Demo
