how to cancel subscription to window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', ) in angular service
I am using angular: 15.2.10 for my project. I have created an angular service which can listen to cookie changes by leveraging the CookieStore Api.
My current code looks as follows:
type CookieChangeType = {
    name: string,
    value: string,
    expires: Date,
    domain: string,
}

interface CookieChangeEvent extends Event {
    changed: CookieChangeType[]
}

type CookieStore = {
    addEventListener: Window["addEventListener"]
}

declare global {
    interface Window {
        cookieStore: CookieStore;
        addEventListener(type: String, listener: (this: Window, ev: CookieChangeEvent) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    }
} 

export class CookieConsentCommonsService {
     
    
    subscribeToConsentCookieChange(callback: () => void): void {
            window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', (event: CookieChangeEvent) => {
                console.log(`Cookie changed: ${change.name} = ${change.value}`);
                callback();            
            });
    }
}

This code works as expected.
On the top of that I would like to be able to cancel the subscription. I have tried to store the subscription for later :
            const sub = window.cookieStore.addEventListener( ...);
            console.log("sub " + sub)

But there is no return from this code and the output message is:
sub undefined

How can I retrieve a reference for created subscription and later on use it to cancel the subscription?

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener
function handleChange() {
  // ...
}

// sub
window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
// unsub
window.cookieStore.removeEventListener('change', handleChange);

or
const controller = new AbortController();

// sub
window.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', handleChange, { signal: controller.signal });
// unsub
controller.abort();

ts
// Cookie interface definition
interface Cookie {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  expires?: Date | null; // Optional expiration time
  path?: string; // Optional path
  domain?: string; // Optional domain
  secure?: boolean; // Optional secure flag
  sameSite?: 'lax' | 'strict' | 'none'; // Optional SameSite attribute
}

// CookieStore interface inheriting from EventTarget
interface CookieStore extends EventTarget {
  get(name: string): Promise<Cookie | null>;
  getAll(): Promise<Cookie[]>;
  set(cookie: Cookie): Promise<void>;
  delete(name: string): Promise<void>;
}

// Adding CookieStore to the global window object
declare global {
  interface Window {
    cookieStore: CookieStore;
  }
}


Yes this should work as CookieStore inherits from EventTarget.

how can I align my iterface so this code will work: declare global {
interface Window {
cookieStore: CookieStore;
addEventListener(type: String, listener: (this: Window, ev: CookieChangeEvent) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}

}

@fascynacja since the interface is not ready/there for CookieStore why don't u type it to any and just write the methods based on MDN docs? So you don't need to worry about typing

@NarenMurali please excuse me, but I am not at all experienced with ts nor front end development and I did not understood what you mean. what does it mean interface is not ready? what does it mean to "type it to any" .

@fascynacja cookieStore: any = (window as any)['cookieStore'];add this to the top of your component,  then use it like this.cookieStore.get('asfd'), angular will not give any errors, but it's your responsibility to see the typing is correct based on documentation online

last thing. How can I read the name of the changed cookie? handleChange is just a simple function and its different than the one I had before as callback: (event: CookieChangeEvent) => {...}

You can try the rxjs way of handling events using fromEvent, I use subscription to unsubscribe the observable stream when the component is destroyed.
cookieStore = (window as any)['cookieStore'];
listener = (callback: () => void, event: any) => {};
private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscribeToConsentCookieChange(() => {});
}

async subscribeToConsentCookieChange(callback: () => void) {
  this.sub.add(
  fromEvent<any>(this.cookieStore, 'change')
    .subscribe((event: any) => {
      console.log(`Cookie changed: `, event);
      callback();
    })
  );
  // this.cookieStore.addEventListener('change', (event: any) => {
  //   console.log(`Cookie changed`);
  //   callback();
  // });
  await this.cookieStore.set('test', 'asdf');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}


Dear @Naren  I have put this code inside my Angular service. The 3rd line: destroy$ = inject(DestroyRef); does not compile saying "TS2304: Cannot find name DestroyRef"

@fascynacja import it, what version of angular are you using, actually for this particular scenario, the other answer is more elegant, but don't type cookieStore and waste your time

I am using angular: 15.2.10. When I try to import I see: TS2305: Module "@angular/core" has no exported member DestroyRef

I just read that DestroyRef is introduced in agular 16. I should have put in the question my angular version, I will update it now.

@fascynacja updated my answer, with angular 15 supported code

@Narel I will try to go with the first answer, because as for now it seems more "obvious" to me what is happening there. I took your advice and removed the methods from cookieStore and otpmized also the Cookie interface so the code is more concise. Ofk I have upvoted your answer since its perfectly working example

@fascynacja no problem, happy coding!
